# What are Allana Solo's Force abilities?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

I'm trying to write a Powers and Abilities section for [Allana Solo on Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Allana_Solo), but I don't know any of her abilities.

Can someone provide a list of all her applications and powers in the Force she has displayed in her brief stint as a character? The Force vision in [*Apocalypse*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Apocalypse) is the best I know of.

Comment: Why are you trying to write a wiki article on her abilities when you don't know what any of them are?

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2068/how-to-handle-what-are-character-name-force-powers-type-questions

Comment: sorry, I checked wookepedia and they didn't have anything listed, can't help you.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield +1 Actually made me laugh out loud at my desk.  Hope my co-workers don't get suspicious and think I'm not working ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Animal Friendship](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Animal_friendship) - Her pet Nexxu is one example but during a stampede caused by and assassination attempt Allana was able to calm several animals saving lives.

[Force Healing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_healing) - She has been wounded a few times and Han has remarked that she is a quick healer just like her mother.

[Mind Trick](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mind_trick) - She has not mastered this one but she has used them on guards and people trying to attack falcon on Dantooine.

[Precognition](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Precognition)- This is probably her strongest and most prominent talent.  Probably first seen while kidnapped on Jacen's flagship.

[Force Bellow](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_bellow) - She was cornered and about to be captured and let out a loud scream that stunned her attacker allowing her to flee.

[Force Stealth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_stealth) - Taught to her by her father when she was very young for her protection

Other than force stealth most of her abilities seem to come naturally and are untrained.